# Openshift: How to remote access MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, openshift

So I just finished setting up a JBoss application server gear on Openshift and I attached a MySQL and **phpmyadmin** cartridges. My question is if there is a way to remote access to the database server using an app like *MySQL Workbench*?

Comment: essentially but from a remote instead

Comment: I think its possible to set up mySQL to allow remote connections without a lot of difficulty. I saw a script years ago that could break into the database without a password however that was on localhost. I would think its possible to connect phpmyadmin using the remote ip address of the SQL server in the config

Comment: haha im not trying to get in trouble here. It should be legal with the right steps.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `rhc port-forward` to forward ports from your database to your local machine.  Check out the tutorial [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift).  The basic idea of port forwarding in this context is that you can forward ports on your local machine to ones on the gear.  So in your case, you would forward some port on your local machine to the port mysql is listening on for connections in your gear.  Then you would connect MySQL Workbench to the port on your local machine.

Comment: do you a link on how to do that? I read some stuff before on it but i didnt understand it

Comment: @Mtn_Wolf, see my edits.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: `port-forwarding` doesn't seems to be a permanent solution. I have a standalone application which needs to communicate to the database. How do I do that?

Comment: Port-forward IS a permament solution.

Comment: Do I have to port-forward on my server or on my local machine?

Comment: Hi Denny.  You should run the port-forward command on the machine you want the ports to be fowarded to.

Answer (score 23):

Use SSH and MysqlWorkbench

SSH commands: (next to rhc ssh myappname)

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST

echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT

echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME

echo $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD
```

MysqlWOrkbench

Create new connection:

Set connection name

set connection method: **Standard TCP/IP over SSH**

Fill SSH hostname = host of yor app, ex: "myappname-user.rhcloud.com"

SSH Username = UUID of your app

SSH Key file = 
  On Windows: **C:\Users\XXX.ssh\id_rsa**
  On OS X: **/Users/XXX/.ssh/**

Click "Test connection" .... and use myqlworkbench

Comment: I persoanally prefer this over forwarding a port. Thanks! Also I was putting 127.0.01 as port, but echoing `$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST` saved the day for me! PS: I've tried with Sequel Pro.

Comment: I can't believe this worked. Especially on Windows... amazing

Answer (score 5):

The solution is explained [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/set-up-local-access-to-openshift-hosted-services-with-port-forwarding) using Linux:

```
rhc port-forward -a app &

rhc app show -a <app>

mysql -u <user>  -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -p
```

After entering your password, you are connected with remote mysql on Openshift.

Answer (score 4):

Login via SSH.

1. Login for SSH
2. export | grep MYSQL
3. View value to OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT

Example:

```
[xxxxxxx.rhcloud.com xxxxxxx]\>  export | grep MYSQL
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_DNS="xxxxxxx-name.rhcloud.com"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_GEAR_UUID="xxxxxxx"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST="xxxxxxx-name.rhcloud.com"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD="nlxxxxxxx"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT="57176"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL="mysql://adminxxxxxxx:nlqxxxxxxx-name.rhcloud.com:57176/"
declare -x OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME="adminxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

To remotely access MySQL on Openshift, you can configure NodePort or LoadBalancer as the type on the Service instead of the default ClusterIP. This will allow external tcp access to your database. Note a nodeport will be defined in the 30000-32767 range by default which will map to the targetport.

Comment: The original question was about OpenShift 2, not OpenShift 3.