# How to write such SQL query statement?

Tags: mysql

I have four tables: foods, recipes, users, and activities.

The activities table has schema:

```
mysql> describe activities;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| recipe_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The recipes table has schema:

```
mysql> describe recipes;
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | image_url    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | food_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The foods-recipes has a one-to-many relationship, and recipes-activities has a many-to-many relationships.

Now I want to select all user activities on foods. I consider a user acting on a food if he acts on a recipe of that food. If a user acts on multiple recipes of the same food, only one should be counted.

Could anyone tell me how to write the query?

Comment: Please read the rules. You are not allowed to ask for answers to questions you have not attempted yourself!

Rule: Do not ask questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Comment: @Mtn_Wolf Is it so? [`See your first question in SO`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19749599/2118383)

Comment: He is not asking for a solution to a problem. They asked for a method to resolve his situation.

Comment: use a [`JOIN`](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: @serakfalcon, I don't know how to detect those recipes linking to the same food. Those activities should be counted only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT activities.user_id,recipes.food_id 
FROM activities 
INNER JOIN recipes ON recipes.id = activities.recipe_id
```

should pull the ID of every food from a recipe that a user uses in activities.
`DISTINCT` ensures that there are no duplicates.

Comment: This will select distinct user_ids. But if user 1 acted on food 1 and 2, it should be counted twice.

Comment: no, it selects distinct user/food pairs. Did you even try to run the query? http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/distinct.php

Comment: Sorry it is. I tried, but the first time made a mistake. Thanks!